# Как остановить выполнение приложения (NDK)?

Tags: android, android-ndk

Вызываю из под Java нативный код на C++.

Несмотря на то, что функция отработала и выдала результат (сохранила его в файл), приложение продолжает работать.

Как можно остановить функцию после выдачи результата?

Comment: Сформулируйте вопрос ещё раз и нормально.

Comment: Непонятно... За такие вопросы полагается минусовать!

Comment: А у вас функция внутри держит поток? или стартует другое приложение?
Или у Вас само приложение остается висеть в памяти после того, как Вы закрыли его?

Answer (score 1):

1. При правильной архитектуре приложения ситуации, когда необходимо принудительно завершать процесс, не возникает. Отработав, функция должна передать управление вызывающему коду.
2. Если процесс таки надо убить, для этого есть разные инструменты, например, [Process.killProcess](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#killProcess%28int%29).